# Why reference of derived class interface shows field of the base class?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, interface

I am creating an abstract base class with properties and inheriting that base class in derived class. The derived class inherits the base class and also an interface. When I try to reference the object of the derived class using interface, I see the properties of the base class also which are not declared in the derived class interface. Original code is bit big but following is the same approach I am following

**Base class:**

```
public class PromotionBase : IPromotionBase
{
    private string CurrentPromotion = string.Empty;
    public PromotionBase(string promotionName)
    {
        CurrentPromotion = promotionName;
    }
    public DateTime? StartDate => SettingsManager.GetSettingDateTime(CurrentPromotion, nameof(this.StartDate));
    public DateTime? EndDate => SettingsManager.GetSettingDateTime(CurrentPromotion, nameof(this.EndDate));
    public string PromoCode => SettingsManager.GetSettingString(CurrentPromotion, nameof(this.PromoCode));
    public DateTime? OrderQualificationStartDate => SettingsManager.GetSettingDateTime(CurrentPromotion, nameof(this.OrderQualificationStartDate));
    public DateTime? OrderQualificationEndDate => SettingsManager.GetSettingDateTime(CurrentPromotion, nameof(this.OrderQualificationEndDate));
    public int DiscountPercentage => SettingsManager.GetSettingInt(CurrentPromotion, nameof(this.DiscountPercentage));
    public int UsageLimit => SettingsManager.GetSettingInt(CurrentPromotion, nameof(this.UsageLimit));
    public string ActivePromoTile => SettingsManager.GetSettingString(CurrentPromotion, nameof(this.ActivePromoTile));
    public string EligiblePromoTile => SettingsManager.GetSettingString(CurrentPromotion, nameof(this.EligiblePromoTile));
    public string AddedPromoTile => SettingsManager.GetSettingString(CurrentPromotion, nameof(this.AddedPromoTile));
    public string VerifiedPromoTile => SettingsManager.GetSettingString(CurrentPromotion, nameof(this.VerifiedPromoTile));
}
```

**Derived class:**

```
public class FreeGiftAndShippingPromotionManager : PromotionBase,IFreeGiftAndShippingPromo
{
    public FreeGiftAndShippingPromotionManager() : base(PromotionHelper.PromoName.FreeGiftAndShipping)
    {
    }
    private static Dictionary<int, ProductItemInfo> productItemInfos = null;
    private static DateTime LastProductInfoRefresh = DateTime.MinValue;
    private const int InfoRefreshInterval = 30;
    private const int LowStockLevel = 10;
    public override int GiftProductItemId
    {
        get
        {
            string defaultProductId = "0";
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(GiftProductItemIds).Not())
            {
                defaultProductId = "0" + GiftProductItemIds.Split(',').FirstOrDefault();
            }
            return Convert.ToInt32(defaultProductId);
        }
    }
            public ProductItemInfo GetProductInfo(int productItemId)
    {
        GetFreshProductInfos();
        return productItemInfos[productItemId];
    }
}
```

**Derived class interface:**

```
public interface IFreeGiftAndShippingPromo
{
    DateTime? StartDate { get; }
    DateTime? EndDate { get; }
    string PromoCode { get; }
    DateTime? OrderQualificationStartDate { get; }
    DateTime? OrderQualificationEndDate { get; }
    int PurchaseThreshold { get; }
    int DisplayPriority { get; }
    bool IsActive { get; }
    string PromoTitle { get; }
    string PromoIntro { get; }
    int GiftProductItemId { get; }
    string GiftProductItemIds { get; }
    bool ShowPopup { get; }
    bool OrderMeetsPromoMinPurchase(Order order);
    string GetCartPromoTile(Order order);
    bool OrderEligibleForFreeGift(Order order);
    string EligiblePromoTile { get; }
    string AddedPromoTile { get; }
    string VerifiedPromoTile { get; }
    ProductItemInfo GetProductInfo(int productItemId);
    string GetCartProductGridDisplay();
}
```

I created this structure so when i reference the interface of the derived class i get the properties which are in the derived class interface only.

But when I reference the interface of the derived class like this

```
private IFreeGiftAndShippingPromo Instance_FreeGiftAndShippingPromoManager = new FreeGiftAndShippingPromotionManager();
```

I can see the **ActivePromoTile** property of the base class too with all other base class properties. May  I know why? Is there a way i can only get members which are declared in the derived class interface?

[Debugger detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPyKl.png)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you provide line of code that clarifies what "I can see the ActivePromoTile property" means? (Clearly you can see source and properties in debugger, but I doubt that is what you are asking).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I have added a screen shot of the debugger. Hope that helps with understanding. Please let me know if you need anything else. I will be happy to give more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debugger shows the actual type that is held in the interface, that is the type you are seeing in the window. If you tried to actually use `ActivePromoTile` in the code the code would not compile.

Comment: Thanks @Scott . Its true when i try to use that it does not show in the intellisense. My bad I was so focused on the debugger showing that property cause of which i forgot to try to use that instance and check.